# Gdalwarp producing odd results around 0 degree longitude

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, proj

I am warping ECMWF grib data (full globe, 0.25 degree resolution) to match the SEVIRI geostationary satellite projection. I use this command:

gdalwarp -overwrite -ot Float32 -t_srs "+proj=geos +a=6378169 +b=6356583.8 +lon_0=0.0 +h=35785831" -te -5570248.832537 5570244.832537 5567248.429179 -5567252.429179 -ts 3712 3712 -wo NUM_THREADS=6 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -q -r cubicspline --config CENTER_LONG 180 /data/ECMWF_T2_20181223T00_000.grib /data/cubicspline.tiff

The output projection looks good, and if I try this with the ECMWF land-sea mask then I can see that it is correct for most of the view.

However, along a vertical centred on zero degrees longitude I see this artefact.[image]

Any ideas what is causing that, and how to resolve it? It artefact appears for all resampling methods *except* nearest neighbour.

(edit) In response to the comment, here's the original data - visualised using QGIS. Obviously there is some problem with how QGIS views ECMWF files, which start at 0 degrees longitude and go to 360 degrees.
Viewing the file in non-GDAL based viewers (such as Panoply) shows no problem.
[image]

Comment: what does the original data look like at this location?

Comment: Original data added. Based on this (which I hadn't looked at in GDAL before) there's obviously some issue with how GDAL handles datasets going from 0->360 rather than -180 -> 180